# Fill empty fields - awk

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns

I have three files,

```
A.txt
DRR033612   184474
DRR033613   232882
DRR033614   66017
DRR033615   189965
DRR033616   118663
DRR029180   8439

B.txt
DRR033615   1
DRR033616   3

C.txt
DRR033615   5
DRR029180   10
DRR033612   20
```

that I want to summarize with the following awk command:

```
cat *.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{unique[$1]=(unique[$1] FS $2); next}END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}'
```

I am basically joining the files based on the first column. `A.txt` contains all items.

Unfortunately, the command does not work the way I want, i.e. the value `20`of the line `DRR033612 20` is not written in the correct field.

This is my output:

```
DRR033614       66017
DRR029180       8439    10
DRR033615       189965  1   5
DRR033616       118663  3
DRR033612       184474  20
DRR033613       232882
```

This is my desired output:

```
DRR033614       66017
DRR029180       8439        10
DRR033615       189965  1   5
DRR033616       118663  3
DRR033612       184474      20
DRR033613       232882
```

**In addition**, I would like that all empty cells get replaced by `0`.

Comment: You've explained it well, but I think it would help even more if you include the output that you want given your sample input. That will give people something definitive to test their solutions against.

Comment: The script needs to notice when the filename changes, and then add default fields to any of the unique elements that hasn't been updated in that pass.

Comment: can you extend your output in case if there would be an entry in `B.txt` or `C.txt` that doesn't exists in `A.txt`? Let's say `B.txt` contains entry `DRR033620   100`

Comment: `A.txt` contains all items

Comment: you should mention that in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays and ARGIND:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ vals[$1][ARGIND] = $2 }
END {
    for (key in vals) {
        printf "%s", key
        for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
            printf "\t%d", vals[key][fileNr]
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk A.txt B.txt C.txt
DRR033614       66017   0       0
DRR029180       8439    0       10
DRR033615       189965  1       5
DRR033616       118663  3       0
DRR033612       184474  0       20
DRR033613       232882  0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

with `join` in a helper function

```
$ function j() { join -a1 -e0 -o1.1,1.2,"$3"2.2 <(sort $1) <(sort $2); } 

$ j <(j file1 file2) file3 1.3, | column -t

DRR029180  8439    0  10
DRR033612  184474  0  20
DRR033613  232882  0  0
DRR033614  66017   0  0
DRR033615  189965  1  5
DRR033616  118663  3  0
```

this is ordered by the key, you can recover the original order of the first file, but it doesn't seem that way in your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to have time maybe tomorrow to write a proper explanation, but this should do the trick:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }\
  { if (ARGIND != previousArg) { 
      previousArg = ARGIND;
      for (i in unique) { unique[i] = (unique[i] FS) }} 
    unique[$1]=(unique[$1] $2); next
  }
END {
  for (i in unique) print i,gensub(/\t\t/, "\t0\t", "g", unique[i])
}' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' \
'{ all[FILENAME][$1] = $2 }
 END{
     for (i in all["A.txt"]) {
         r = i OFS all["A.txt"][i];
         r = r OFS int(all["B.txt"][i]) OFS int(all["C.txt"][i]);
         print r
     }
 }' A.txt B.txt C.txt
```

The output:

```
DRR033614   66017   0   0
DRR029180   8439    0   10
DRR033615   189965  1   5
DRR033616   118663  3   0
DRR033612   184474  0   20
DRR033613   232882  0   0
```